# Wrong output values: zero or NaN

Tags: arrays, fortran, output, gfortran, fortran95

There are two variables I want to write to a file, after the math is done in the subroutine. Let`s say X and Y.
Since the size of my X,Y-array is unknown, I allocate it.

The point is that if I tell fortran to write the array in the IDE-own output terminal it works fine.
But if I want to have it in an .DAT file, only the first 4 rows in that .DAT-file are correct, meaning the values are not zero.
All the following rows on the other side are either zero(most) or NaN (few).

Here`s the relevant code:

```
integer :: i       
type YX
    real :: Y
    real :: X
end type
type(YX),allocatable, dimension(:)  :: yx_array

allocate(yx_array(i))

i=0  !Start
dx=1.E-1
yx_array(i)%Y=Y0     !Y0 and X0 are known
yx_array(i)%X=X0  

do  while (yx_array(i)%Y>1.E-3)  
    i=i+1        
    yx_array(i)%X=X0+i*dx

    yx_array(i)%Y= f( yx_array(i)%X ) ! just some math..
end do

open(UNIT=99,File='Values',status='Replace',position='rewind')

!Since i now defines the size of the array I can't overwrite it by i=0, 
!therefore I start with n=0 and go up to i-1. Not i though, because Y(i=max) !is a negative value which I don't need in my data.

do n=0,i-1
    write(99,100) vektor(n)%Y, vektor(n)%X
    100 format(2(F8.3,2X)
    end do
close(99)
```

[image: values of Y and X]

I just can't figure out what the problem might be.

Comment: Fortran starts indexing arrays at `1` unless told otherwise... You are probably addressing the array out-of-bounds.

Comment: Use the option `-Wall -Wextra  -fcheck=all` while compiling your program. It will help catch most mistakes. Apart from that, your "relevant code" is not really relevant in that someone who want to help you can not simply compile and run it. For example, you use `i` to allocate while it is uninitialized. In addition to that make sure that you use `implicit none` in your program to force yourself to declare all variables.

Comment: Enter the output values as text and not as a picture next time please. Read in the help section how to write your questions here in a best way.